# Tkinter: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning Tkinter and I'm trying to use an OOP approach in designing a simple GUI.

I'm creating a class that is inheariting from tkinter.Frame and also implements my specific functionalities.

I'm trying to define a tkinter.StringVar() outside the **init** function of my class and I get the error described in the title. Now I know that I should have my variable inside the **init** method and I got it to work I just want to understand why is not working if I declare it as a class variable.

I understand that tk.StringVar() needs to have a tk.Tk() context to be able to run. So this should(and indeed does) compile with no errors:

```
root = tk.Tk()
str = tk.StringVar()
root.mainloop()
```

If I write like this however it will give the mentioned error:

```
class myClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(myClass, self).__init__(master)
        pass
    str=tk.StringVar()

root = tk.Tk()
inst = myClass(root)
```

So this is if I would try to write tk.StringVar() without creating the 'root=tk.Tk()' first. But to my understanding the tk.Tk() context is created before I create the 'inst' instance so by the time the interpreter goes into the class and sees that class variable 'str' it should have already ran tk.Tk(). Obviously I'm missing something. Please explain to me the sequence in which things take place and why is that root.Tk() not executed before I try creating a tk.StringVar() variable. Thank you.

Edit: The line str=tk.StringVar() is part of the class body, and therefore executes during the definition of the class - which happens before Tk() is instantiated. 
Thank you @jasonharper for the answer.

Comment: The line `str=tk.StringVar()` is part of the class body, and therefore executes during the definition of the class - which happens before `Tk()` is instantiated.

Comment: thanks. how do I accept your answer as the solution? :D I'm new here

Comment: Notify @jasonharper that you would like to have his comment as an answer (I just did, no need for you to repeat it now) and then upvote/accept.

Comment: ok thank you I will